# Emacs or Vim keybindings with Code::Blocks?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, codeblocks

I am using CodeBlocks for C++ development, and I would like to use more productive keybindings. Emacs or Vi style keybindings would be great, but I cannot figure out how to enable this. I tried installing the `codeblocks-contrib` package, went to `settings > editor > keybindings`, but the options are very limited. For example, I could not find a line up/line down keybinding, forward/backward word, etc.

Ideally, I would be able to import my existing keybinding config files from my Eclipse or IntelliJ IDE's. Is there a way to do this, or simply set up my CodeBlocks keybindings manually?